# Trigger to run TeamCity based on file existence

Tags: triggers, teamcity

I want to run TeamCity processes based on file existance.

I have two TeamCity processes (`Dev` and `Prod`):

- `Dev` should be run if there is `DevParam` file in repo (or in specified location).
- `Prod` should be run if there is `ProdParam` file.

I want to run exactly one process after each push to repository.

This files will be added and removed like:

- [0] Repository has `DevParam` file
- [1] Pushed, there is still `DevParam` file `->` `Dev` process should be run
- [2] Pushed, removed `DevParam` file and added `ProdParam` `->` `Prod` process should be run
- [3] Pushed, there is still `ProdParam` `->` `Prod` should be run

I tried to create Trigger with rules, but I failed (rule like `+:DevParam` run also on file removal).

Git recognizes addind and removing this files as Moving with Rename, so it may be relevant.

Comment: which VCS do you use? do you aware about git-flow?

Comment: We are using git. I know about add, commit, push, merge etc.. We are using really simplistic Workflow - developer pushes to dedicated branch, and we want TeamCity to start (as described in question).

Comment: file management is not a normal process. I strongly advise you to use the branch flow. For your example use develop branch(DevParam) for an all your developers and master branch for a prod.

Answer (score 1):

file management is not a normal process. I strongly advise you to use the branch flow. For your example, use `develop` branch(DevParam) for an all your developers and `master` branch for a prod

Try to use the follows advice.

The developers are coding in the `dev` branch. Each developer working only this branch. 
You should create the build configuration with the trigger to your `dev` branch. After each new commit, the configuration will be triggered.

If you decided that the code in the `dev` branch is ready to production, you just merged all to the `master`. And now you can also trigger the same configuration only for a `master` branch.

For more information about gitflow-workflow read [this](https://ru.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)